# Mac completely uninstall php that was not installed from brew

Tags: php, macos

I'm running Mac Catalina and want to remove the php version to downgrade to php7.2 **possibly use brew from now on.**

At the moment I have this.

I don't care much about the error but want I want to achieve is removing completely remove 7.3.11 and then reinstall from brew. I can't find anything about replacing php that is not coming from brew. Please help.

```
$ php -v
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_imap.dll' (tried: /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/php_imap.dll (dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/php_imap.dll, 0x0009): dlopen(): file not found: /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/php_imap.dll), /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/php_imap.dll.so (dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/php_imap.dll.so, 0x0009): dlopen(): file not found: /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/php_imap.dll.so)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP 7.3.11 (cli) (built: Jun  5 2020 23:50:40) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.11, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

Comment: my 7.2.xx is brewed in, and the distro 7.3.11 is laying dormant, never to be heard again.  You just have to make certain that in you PATH env variable, the proper path is top dog, and also ensure that in apache (if you use that), you load the proper libphp7.so, as installed by brew.

Comment: Php is running out of brew, that's why php -I or -v gives me the 7.3 version running. Where should I look?

Answer (score 9):

I found myself how to do it. I was looking at my user folder while the .profile file was in the root folder. Then I just put this inside:

export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/bin:$PATH"

If you want to change the  php version see the versions you have in /usr/local/opt/ and change the .profile file. Just reboot after the change.

I hope it will help somebody.

Comment: *"Yes, exactly!"* It's very common to find yourself using this sort of solution on all kinds of systems:  the operating system has thus-and-such version in `/usr/bin` and you install other versions that you need somewhere in `/usr/local` ... which of course is a directory that is set-aside specifically for this use.  Then, simply ensure that the version you need is first in the `$PATH`, and that other environment-variables are also set appropriately.  (The Python language has elevated this into a science with their "virtual environment" (virtualenv) feature ...)